# Duda array de bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

estaba intentando hacer lo siguiente:
   Hacer un script que agregue a un arreglo todos los archivos del directorio /home cuya terminacion sea .doc
MI SOLUCION:

```
 vector=()  
 guardar=0  
 for i in `find /home -name *.doc`; do       
      vector[$guardar]=$i        
     let guardar=guardar+1  
 done
```

Esta bien hecho? Gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 4):

El mayor problema con dicho código es esta parte:

```
for i in `find /home -name *.doc`
```

Es probable que creas que la variable `i` toma el valor de cada línea de la salida del comando `find`, pero esto no es así. En realidad ocurre lo siguiente:

1. El comando `find` es ejecutado.
2. La salida del comando sufre el efecto conocido como [***word splitting***](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).
3. El resultado del paso anterior sufre el efecto conocido como [***filename expansion***](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).
4. Los elementos resultantes son utilizados por el comando `for` para ser asignados a la variable `i` en su iteración correspondiente.

Dicho de otra forma, **el proceso fallará si alguno de los nombres de archivo contiene caracteres que provoquen *filename expansion* o *word splitting***.

Es decir, si la salida de `find` fuera esta:

```
./archivo 1.doc
./archivo 2.doc
./archivo *.doc
```

El contenido del arreglo sería este (cada línea es un elemento del arreglo):

```
./archivo
1.doc
./archivo
2.doc
./archivo
archivo 1.doc
archivo 2.doc
archivo *.doc
```

Por otro lado, no es necesario gestionar manualmente los índices del arreglo. Puedes usar la sintaxis `arreglo+=(elemento)` para que Bash haga ese trabajo por ti.

Dicho lo anterior, se me ocurren al menos dos métodos para lidiar con esta situación.

#### Método 1: [*Filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

Este es el método nativo, pero no es tan rápido ni tan potente como `find`:

```
for archivo in "${HOME}"/*.doc; do
  arreglo+=( "${archivo}" )
done
```

```
shopt -s dotglob globstar

for archivo in "${HOME}"/**/*.doc; do
  arreglo+=( "${archivo}" )
done
```

El primero busca archivos dentro del directorio `${HOME}` que coincidan con el patrón `*.doc`. El segundo hace lo mismo pero de manera recursiva, incluyendo directorios ocultos.

#### Método 2: [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) + [*process substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

Útil si prefieres usar `find` pero evitando los efectos del *filename expansion*, *word splitting* y el uso de `for`:

```
mapfile -t arreglo < <(find "${HOME}" -name '*.doc')
```

Con GNU `find` incluso podrías usar la opción `-print0` para evitar problemas con saltos de línea en los nombres de archivo:

```
mapfile -d '' -t arreglo < <(find "${HOME}" -name '*.doc' -print0)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por la respuesta me sirvio muchisimo, en serio, de todas formas si lo quisiera agregar manualmente al arreglo realizando la instruccion que detalle anteriormente : vector[$guardar]=$i. Seria valido hacerlo asi o se deberia de escribir de otra forma?